# Bootstrap dropdown menu nested in form: tabindex breaks on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a [Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns) which lives inside of a  element, between two text input fields.

The dropdown's role="menu" attribute allows it to be navigated using the up/down arrow and Enter keys. However, when I make my selection in the dropdown and hit "Enter" the tabindex of the form is reset back to the first input instead of tabbing to the next input field.

Is there a way to focus on the next field in the form without explicitly doing this via JS or a custom tabindex order?

Answer (score 1):

The only option you have is to change bootstrap.js and include the js function there if you don't want to add a new JS file. Bootstrap is done with a combination of CSS and HTML, the behaviour is defined by you. Bootstrap does not provide you methods to handle the behaviour of the elements.

This is the function you need, to handle the behaviour described above. I have tested the function locally and it will handle the enter keypress action as well.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function(){    
document.getElementById("#myDivId").focus();
```

});

Hope this helps!